# What is the best way to make a C# MVC Controller responde a JSON?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm in a serius dilema. What kind of service I use to convert a object to JSON?

---

Frist scenario:

I use the serializer of Microsoft, the code will be like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Get(string param)
    {
        return Json(result);
    }
```

---

Second scenario:

I use the Newtonsoft, example code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public string Get(string param)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
    }
```

---

What do I do? Who is better, safer or quicker?

I try to found the response in the documentation but I still have doubt.

Comment: Just a thought, have you checked out [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)? Its designed for this specific use case, with no serialization required on your part.  I suggest it because your title says "easiest way"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework's `JsonResult` is appropriate 99% of the time. It's been shown that JSON.NET is faster but serialization isn't your typical bottleneck. So unless you NEED JSON.NET stick with the default. By the way, your 2nd scenario as-is doesn't return `application/json` content but `text/html`.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answerer makes a good point, but I can provide an answer based on how I approached the problem.

In my controller I have a route/function that actually looks for json in a file, but you could also serialize an object using Newtonsoft nuget package code.

```
    public ActionResult XData(string id)
    {
        string dir = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["X_Path"];

        //search for the file
        if (Directory.Exists(dir) && System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, id, "X.json")))
        {
            //read the file
            string contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(dir, id, "X.json"));

            //return contents of the file as json
            return Content(contents, "application/json");
        }
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }
```